# Grep with context about matched lines in Windows

Tags: windows, grep

I want to search in files, recursively, with a pattern for the filename, for a given string, in a Windows 7 command prompt.
I am familiar with Unix.
So far,

```
findstr /spin /c:"main" *.py
```

is a good replacement for

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec grep -nH "main" {} \;
```

Now, if I want to show some context for each matched line (some lines before and after), how would I do that?
The Unix command is

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec grep -nH -B 2 -A 2 "main" {} \;
```

As of now, I used MinGW, and I guess UnxUtils, GnuWin32, etc. may work, but I am looking for a native Windows command or sequence/pipe of commands.

**EDIT**:
There is already one good answer posted, which gives a continuous, single-colored output. As a spun-off question, is there any way of colorizing the first line of the sequence reported for each find, so one can readily distinguish each sequence?
Can the info about file/line no. be also colorized?
It would be good to have something configurable in the profile (e.g., by greping ">"), so the same command given in the solution gives an output with colors.
[Powershell: Properly coloring Get-Childitem output once and for all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406434/powershell-properly-coloring-get-childitem-output-once-and-for-all) is probably relevant...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 has Powershell already installed.

for Powershell command line

WIN+R   powershell

then from the powershell command prompt you can try something like

```
gci -r -fi '*.py' | Select-String -patt "main" -context 2,3
```

where   gci is Get-ChildItem
    -r or -recurse for recursive
    -fi or -filter for the matching files *.py
    -patt or pattern for matching string "main"
    -co or -context 2,3 for 2 lines before 3 after

lines output with the greater than symbol at start indicate the matching lines

----------------EDIT BELOW--------------------

Tidied up to make output more readable & with colour for file and context line.

```
gci -r -fi '*.py'| Select-String -pattern "main" -context 2,3 | foreach { "";
$padlength = (”{0}       ” -f $_.LineNumber).Length
$pad = ” “*$padlength
$drawlength = (”{0}{1}: ” -f $_.Path, $_.LineNumber).Length
$draw = "-"*$drawlength
$(""| foreach {$_.Trim().Insert(0,$draw)});"";""
Write-Host -Fore Blue $_.Path; "";""
$($_.Context.PreContext | foreach {$_.Trim().Insert(0,$pad)})
Write-Host -Fore Magenta $(”LINE {0}: {1}” -f $_.LineNumber, ($_.Line).Trim())
$($_.Context.PostContext | foreach {$_.Trim().Insert(0,$pad)})
"";""}
```

referenced from:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2013/01.aspx